# How to find $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ and $P\left(x\right)-P\left(x-1\right)=x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to find $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ and $P\left(x\right)-P\left(x-1\right)=x^2$.

After expanding the binomial in $P(x-1)$, I end up getting
$3ax^2-3ax+2bx+a-b=x^2$. What next? Using $3a = 1$ doesn't work.

Comment: Expand $P(x)-P(x-1)= (\ldots)\cdot x^2+(\ldots)\cdot x+(\ldots)$ and compare coefficients with $x^2+0x+x$.

Comment: You missed out $3ax^2-3ax+2bx+a-b\color{red}{+\boldsymbol{c}}=x^2$. It should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it does work. As you let $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$, we have $P(x)-P(x-1)=3ax^2-(3a-2b)x+a-b+c$

Now just compare the coefficients. That is, $3a=1$, $3a-2b=0$, $a-b+c=0$ which after solving gives $a=\frac13 , b=\frac12 , c=\frac16$.

Comment: my bad, missed out the $ +c $

Answer (score 3):

> *For the sake of a different method:*

$$
\begin{cases}
P(x)-P(x-1)=x^2  \\
P'(x)-P'(x-1)=2x  \\
P''(x)-P''(x-1)=2 
\end{cases} 
$$
or writing derivatives explicitly:
$$
\begin{cases}
a\big(x^3-(x-1)^3\big)+b\big(x^2-(x-1)^2\big)+c\big(x-(x-1)\big)=x^2~~~~~~~(1) \\
3a\big(x^2-(x-1)^2\big)-2b\big(x-(x-1)\big)=2x~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2) \\
6a\big(x-(x-1)\big)=2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (3)
\end{cases}
$$
Beginning from the end, it's very easy to solve for $a,b,c$:

- First, find $\boxed{a=\frac{1}{3}}$ from the $(3)$.
- Second, plug $a$ into $(2)$ and find $\boxed{b=\frac{1}{2}}$.
- Third, plug $a$ and $b$ into $(1)$ and find $\boxed{c=\frac{1}{6}}$

Each step yields a trivial linear equation.

Comment: seems like a quick way to do what's required; sadly I still haven't covered differential equations. Will take a look at them tomorrow ! I will study them this year but I want to become familiar with the concepts I am gonna encounter...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively. We see that $p(0)=0$.

If $x=1$ we get $$1 = p(1)-p(0) = a+b+c \implies \boxed{a+b+c=1}$$

If $x=2$ we get $$4 = p(2)-p(1) = 7a+3b+c \implies \boxed{7a+3b+c=4}$$

If $x=-1$ we get $$1 = p(0)-p(-1) = a-b+c \implies \boxed{a-b+c=1}$$

Now solve this system...

Comment: Seems quite fast!