# Find all the polynomials such that $P(x)-P(x-1)=x^2$ and $P(0)=0$

Tags: polynomials, summation

Find all the polynomials $p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p(x)-p(x-1)=x^2$ and $p(0)=0$. And then deduce the value of $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ for any natural $n$.

I get, using the initial condition and making induction, that $p(n)$ has to be equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ for any given $n$. From here I think I can use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and conclude that $p(x)=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$. But I feel like this answer is not what the problem is looking for. I do not even know if my answer is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ and $P\left(x\right)-P\left(x-1\right)=x^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781197/how-to-find-a-b-c-such-that-px-ax3bx2cx-and-p-leftx-right-p-l)

Comment: It partially does, thank you @peterwhy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is correct. To explicitly calculate the polynomial, note that $x^n - (x-1)^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ gives a polynomial of degree n-1. By this argument, we cannot have terms that have power greater than 3, therefore our polynomial must be of the form $$p(x) = ax^3 +bx^2 + cx$$
where there is no constant term as $p(0) = 0$. calculating $p(x) - p(x-1)$ and equating it to $x^2$, we get $$p(x) - p(x-1) = (3a)x^2 + (2b-3a)x + (a-b+c)$$
We must have $3a = 1 \Rightarrow a = \frac{1}{3}$, $2b-3a = 0 \Rightarrow b = \frac{1}{2}$  and $a-b+ c  = 0 \Rightarrow c = \frac{1}{6}$. Therefore the polynomial is $$p(x) = \dfrac{2x^3 + 3x^2 + x}{6} = \dfrac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$$

For the second part, we have $$\sum_{i =1} ^n i^2 = \sum_{i =1} ^n (p(i) - p(i-1))  = p(n) - p(0) = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ Using our polynomial from the first part and the fact that the series is a telescoping series.

Comment: This is what I think the problem was asking for, thank you @SStormM